# what does $\|f\|_{C^{k,\alpha}}$ mean?

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading a reference paper by Elgini and Jeong titled "Symmetries and Critical Phenomena in Fluids" ([arXiv:1610.09701](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09701)).

There appeared two expressions:
$$u_0\in C^0\left([0,T];C^{k,\alpha}\right)\tag{1}$$
$$\|\nabla u\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq C_{k,\alpha}\|u(t)\|_{C^{k,\alpha}}\tag{2}$$

***Question:***
what does $\|u(t)\|_{C^{k,\alpha}}$ mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the editing.

Comment: $k$ times continuously differentiable functions the $k$th derivative of which is $\alpha$ Hölder continuous, resp the norm of that space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments: $\newcommand{\n}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|} \n{f}_{C^{k,\alpha}}$ refers to a norm on $k$-times-continuously differentiable functions with Hölder parameter $\alpha$.

*To dive a little deeper (and to give something a little more permanent than a linked-to article on Wikipedia), and give the question a fuller answer, however...*

First, some preliminaries:

- Define the ***Hölder coefficient*** of $f$ (domain $\Omega$) w.r.t. $\alpha$ by

$$|f|_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)} := \sup_{\substack{x,y \in \Omega \\ x \ne y}} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{ \|x-y\|^\alpha }$$

- A ***multi-index*** is a tuple of nonnegative integers, $\beta := (\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}^n$. We denote $|\beta| := \sum \beta_i$. Their primary use is in compactifying derivative notations by writing $\partial^\beta = \partial_1^{\beta_1} \partial_2^{\beta_2} \cdots \partial_n^{\beta_n}$ where $\partial_i$ denotes the partial derivative in the $i$th coordinate.
- We may define a $C^k$ norm for multivariable functions by
  $$
  \n{f}_{C^{k}(\Omega)} := \max_{|\beta| \le k} \left( \sup_{x \in \Omega} \left| \partial^\beta f(x) \right| \right)
  $$
  referencing ordinary absolute values for clarity (analogous to the usual sup-norms applied in the one-dimensional case).

Then we define,

$$\n{f}_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)} := \n{f}_{C^k(\Omega)} + \max_{|\beta|=k} \left| \partial^\beta f \right|_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)}$$

Comment: thanks a lot for the explicit answer! this is exactly what I am looking. Currently I am travelling in a place where I can not access wikipedia.